# When to close file stream

Tags: c#, sharpziplib, data-stream

I reading a file in a zip file using streams like this :

```
public static Stream ReadFile(Models.Document document, string path, string password, string fileName)
        {
            FileStream fsIn = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(path, $"{document.guid}.crypt"));
            var zipFile = new ZipFile(fsIn)
            {
                //Password = password,
                IsStreamOwner = true
            };



                var zipEntry = zipFile.GetEntry(fileName);
                //zipEntry.AESKeySize = 256;
                Stream zipStream = zipFile.GetInputStream(zipEntry);
                return zipStream;
        }
```

I'm having trouble closing the filestream fsIn as it is not available when I return from the ReadFile method and if I close it within the method the stream zipStream that I'm returning will be closed.
How can I close fsIn but still read the data-stream returned from my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your return type to be an object that contains both the parent `FileStream` and the inner file-stream so that the consumer of your function can close both streams when they need to - alternatively you could subclass `Stream` with your own type that then assumes ownership of both streams. It's probably simpler to do the former as otherwise you'd have to proxy all `Stream` methods.

Like so:

```
sealed class ReadFileResult : IDisposable
    // (use a `sealed` class with a non-virtual Dispose method for simpler compliance with IDisposable)
{
    private readonly FileStream zipFileStream;
    public Stream InnerFileStream { get; }

    internal ReadFileResult( FileStream zipFileStream, Stream innerFileStream )
    {
        this.zipeFileStream = zipFileStream;
        this.InnerFileStream = innerFileStream;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.InnerFileStream.Dispose();
        this.zipFileStream.Dispose();
    }
}

public static ReadFileResult ReadFile(Models.Document document, string path, string password, string fileName)
{
    // ...
    return new ReadFileResult( zipFileStream: fsIn, innerFileStream: zipStream );
}
```

Consumed like so:

```
void Foo()
{
    using( ReadFileResult rfr = ReadFile( ... ) )
    {
        Stream s = rdr.InnerFileStream;

        // ..
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yea..
That did it..  Thanks